# Solr scaling multiple instance and shard or multiple solr for different collection

Tags: solr

I'm new with solr, and have some case with scaling. I have plan with 2 collection in solr and planning to scale it

- Song Collection (primary for searching). currently ~20m data, indexing 100k data/daily
- Traffic Collection (primary for faceting later), currently ~100m data, indexing 1m data/daily

currently i have 3 solrcloud connect with zk, and have rare case solr down because too many indexing data to traffic collection.

which one is good for performance all, moreover the server only have 3 Server each is 32x3GB RAM and 16 core (shared)

- deploy solrcloud with multiple instance, i.e i have 6 solr connect with zk
- deploy multiple solrcloud and separated collection,

  - 3 solr with zk for song collection only
  - another 3 solr with zk for traffic collection only (this separated solr with previous one)

Or maybe any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at keeping a single cluster as long as is manageable. But you can improve how you deal with the traffic collection (songs collection sounds ok):

- at this rate it will be too large for a single collection eventually
- show why not index traffic in daily/weekly/or yearlly collections?
- your collections will remain manageable size, and when querying you will be more efficient, as many times you don't need to query the whole history, just last day, last month etc

This is a very recurrent set up.

Comment: so, song + collection in single cluster cloud is more preferred? daily/weekly means only resume model data from daily/weekly or all data will indexing daily/weekly i.e at 3am?

Comment: no, I mean 1 song collection, and 1 daily traffic collection (instead of daily, it could be weekly, or monthly etc).

Comment: ohh. if i divide into monthly collection, i.e collection already 1y.o. is it affect in performance if there are many collection in solr? or should i archive them?

Comment: there is a point where there are too many collections, but having for instance 100 collections won't be a problem (regarding the number of collections itself), so you will notice when it's starting to be a problem, and then you can move to a new cluster or archive them/collapse them into fewer